# Unable to bind using Angularjs+Ajax

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

i am unable to bind the result to a html table. Through ajax call i am able to get the values Please look into my code so you will get an idea what i am trying to do`

```js
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
             app.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {
                 $scope.ProductList = [];
                 $scope.fillProductList = function () {
                 var httpreq = {
                     method: 'POST',
                     url: "Try2.aspx/DistrictAnalysis",
                     headers: {
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                         'dataType': 'json'
                     },
                     data: {}
                 }
           
                 $http(httpreq).success(function (response) {
                     $scope.ProductList = response.d;
            
                 })
             };
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
       <a href="#xyz" ng-click="fillProductList()">
         </a>
   </div>
<table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>city</th>
                                <th>DevelopmentPercentage</th>
                              
                            </tr>
                             <tr   ng-repeat="product in ProductList">
                                <td>{{product.City}}</td>
                                <td>{{product.DevelopmentPercentage}}</td>
                                
                           </tr>
                        </table>
```

`

Comment: first check response in console network tab or console log the response

Comment: @Phani, try using `response.data.d` instead of `response.d`

Comment: @Shailesh Singh looked at console log window its retuning [object Object]
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: null
      },
      config: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         data: { },
         headers: { },
         method: "POST",
         transformRequest: [ ],
         transformResponse: [ ],
         url: "Try2.aspx/DistrictAnalysis"
      },
      data: { },
      status: 200,
      statusText: "OK"
   }

Comment: Ok, there is no any product detail in your log